# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework Dependent models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For a new project ASP.NET MVC with the Entity Framework (database first) for the database models is used.

For most of the dependecies between models (tables) I use a ListBox which is fine. I also have relations where that is not possible. For that, it is required to add first another object before the main object.

Example: I have products that have an image that can be uploaded and are stored in the table FileStoreDocument where all documents/Pictures are stored and can be reused.

Product (fileStoreDocumentId) -> FileStoreDocument (id)

How can i create the FileStoreDocument first and add it to the Product? all is on the same page. the Model used in the controller ProductController is the product model class.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "....")] Product product)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
db.Product.Add(product);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
return View(product);
}
```

View:

```
@model Cereus.Models.product
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Add new product";
}
....
```

Product Class:

```
public partial class Product
{
public int id { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> validFrom { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> validUntil { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> alteredOn { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> isDeleted { get; set; }
public int productTypeId { get; set; }
public int companyDeliveryId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> companyProducedById { get; set; }
public int serieTypeId { get; set; }
public string longname { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> priceEffective { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> usedFrom { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> usedUntil { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> unusedFrom { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> unusedUntil { get; set; }
public int length { get; set; }
public int width { get; set; }
public int height { get; set; }
public int weight { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> buildYear { get; set; }
public string productionCountry { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> xpos { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> ypos { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> zpos { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> dposx { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> rating { get; set; }
public int vat { get; set; }
public string description { get; set; }
public string label { get; set; }
public bool isInFolder { get; set; }
public bool isOnSite { get; set; }
public int fileStoreDocumentId { get; set; }

public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
public virtual Company Company1 { get; set; }
public virtual FileStoreDocument FileStoreDocument { get; set; }
public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
public virtual SerieType SerieType { get; set; }
}
```

FileStoreDocument:

```
public partial class FileStoreDocument
{
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
public FileStoreDocument()
{
this.FileStoreMetaData = new HashSet<FileStoreMetaData>();
this.Product = new HashSet<Product>();
}

public int id { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> validFrom { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> validUntil { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> alteredOn { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> isDeleted { get; set; }
public int applicationUserId { get; set; }
public int filestoreId { get; set; }
public string longname { get; set; }
public string fileType { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> timeCreated { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> timeLastModified { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> isEncrypted { get; set; }

public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
public virtual Filestore Filestore { get; set; }
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<FileStoreMetaData> FileStoreMetaData { get; set; }
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If `product` in the action method has a `FileStoreDocument` connected to it, it will be added too.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is it possible to give a small example or explain a bit more? thanks!

Comment: Well, what does `product` contain? If it has a `FileStoreDocument` it will be added too. You don't have to create it first, EF will insert both in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the Create page you can simply say:
`@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.FileStoreDocument.fileType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })` and that works fine.

Comment: When I  want to save `Product` i get a FK Violation because `FileStoreDocument` is `NULL` and the `fileStoreDocumentId` property is 0 even when i set the properties as shown above. so i'm missing something.